# other computer in the network cannot connect to mysql database

Tags: networking, mysql, vb.net

I have a vb.net program that uses mysql as its database. And it works when the computer has wampservr installed. But the program gets an unhandled exception error when the computer where its running does not have a wampserver. The only thing that is installed in it is the mysql connector net. How do I make it work. I just want the two programs to access the same mysql database. I already opened port 20 by configuring firewall. Both in TCP and UDP. What do I do? Do I have to tweak the codes?
Anyone in here who have tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you grant access to the target database from the other host?

Assuming the IP of the other computer is 1.2.3.4:

```
$ mysql -u root -p <database_name>
mysql> grant all on db_name.* to <user_name>@1.2.3.4 identified by '<password>';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

(of course you'll want to limit that grant statement to whatever is appropriate for your environment)

Oh, and what does TCP/UDP port 20 have to do with MySQL? By default, MySQL uses port 3306/tcp.

Comment: what would be the username?I have also installed mysql admin on the pc w/ wampserver. Is it the users that I have defined in mysql admin?

Comment: Most likely, yes. This would be whatever username your application is using to connect to mysql.